# Viewing Multiple Grouped Data as ESRI Map Service in ArcGIS Explorer Online

Tags: arcgis-desktop, rest, map-service, online, arcgis-explorer

I'm trying to add ESRI Map Service to ArcGIS Explorer Online. This map service consists of 3 group layers, one of which contains 3 further subgroups. I tried adding my mapservice to the web viewer using the following URL REST interface structure:

http://myserver/ArcGIS/rest/services/myservicename/MapServer

However, this returns no results. The viewer recognizes the map service, and when I add it up, I can see all the layers and individual shapefiles in the legend window, but not in the actual viewer. It also recognizes the spatial extent for each layer - when I zoom in on a particular layer, the viewer centres on the correct extent. I can turn them on and off in the legend but I am unable to see them.

When I add each individual map service layer separately it works fine (with the exception of a couple of layers), as follows:

http://myserver/ArcGIS/rest/services/myservicename/MapServer/2

The other odd aspect is that the same map service works properly in ArcGIS.com map viewer, even when added by its general map service name (http://myserver/ArcGIS/rest/services/myservicename/MapServer).
Basically, my question is whether you can add an ESRI map service to ArcGIS Explorer Online with multiple grouped data in a single operation, just as in ArcGIS.com?

I'd appreciate any help as I've been unable to find an answer elsewhere.

Thanks,
Magda

P.S. I'm going to post cross post on the http://forums.arcgis.com/

Comment: I found the cross-posting referred to [**here**](http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/47851-viewing-multiple-grouped-data-as-esri-map-service-in-arcgis-explorer-online)

Comment: This question appears to have been abandoned.  It was asked 18 months ago, has had no activity, and its asker last logged in 9 months ago.  Consequently, I propose that it be closed.